# Scifi novel. Man kills psychic monk and is sent to live with savages. Ultimately returns to depose his former masters

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to learn the name of a book that I read about 10-15 years ago. There were two groups of people in this book, those who were a part of society, and a second group of people who lived apart from this society.  The people in this society were taught that these people were savages.  There was a police-like force that were linked mentally, they were called priests or monks, that enforced the rules.

One scene sticks out in my mind.  The hero of the story, a man, killed several of these 'monks' by destroying some type of aircraft or vehicle I think. He was forced to live with one of the 'savages', a women, who slowly began to accept him as he learned how to live apart from society.  They fell in love and eventually he turned on the rulers of his former life with the help of his new friends.  I also think that the main character was killed at the end of the book.

Anyone know the name of this book?  I remember it was in the sci-fi section of my local library, but have not been able to find it since.  I remember that the art on the spine of the book caught my eye.  **The word "wall" or "fence" might be in the title?**

Comment: About how long ago did you read it? Is "years ago" more like 5 years or 50 years?

Comment: It was probably 10 or 15 years ago.  I don't know if the book was newly released at that time.

Comment: What was the art on the spine that caught your eye?

Comment: That's hard to answer.  I was just browsing, not looking for any book in particular.  Perhaps it wasn't the art that caught my attention, but rather the title.  I wish I had more information for you.  I'm tempted to go to the library tonight and look at every book in the science fiction section.